# Transform UIView from center

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation

I have a `UIView` in my app that I'd like to give a small scale animation. The animation should be bouncy, as in that it should scale a bit smaller and then back to it's original size.

I found the following Objective-C code:

```
headerView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.9, 0.9);
```

Now, I added this to my Swift code:

```
profileView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: 0.9, y: 0.9)
```

However, what happens now is that the view transforms with the left, top corner seemingly as the anchor. I'd like the center to be anchor, though. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use identity matrix,
try just like this

```
view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.9, y: 0.9)
```